# Use same local database in independent projects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a solution with several projects:

- A class library that just contains the database
  context, lets call it DatumClassLibrary.
- A class library that contains model entities, lets call
  it ModelsClassLibray
- A class library that contains repositories for the model
  entities of ModelsClassLibray, lets call it RepositoriesClassLibrary.

Besides that I have to other projects, one is an MVC5 application and the other is a WebApi application.

How can I use the same local db file both from the MVC5 application and the WebApi application, using entity framework code first?

Comment: Use the same connection string.

Comment: Actually classes in RepositoryClassLibrary and DatumClassLibrary should be defined within the same assembly, cause of this is all data access

Answer (score 0):

EF doesn't care how/where you use it...
Just pass the correct connection string in the Context's constructor every time you use it